# Cannot Archive iPhone Project

Tags: iphone

I got this error while i try to archive iphone project

"Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127"

But I can run on Simulator and iPhone as well. Only I cannot archive.

What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you running any shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are running a shell script and it can't find your specific file. Look at Target -> Build-Phases -> RunScript if you are running a script.

You can check if a script is running in your build output (in the navigator panel). If your script does something wrong, the build-phase will stop.
Also make sure there is no space in shell script deceleration that will definitely throw an error.